# Is DD4T Tridion 2013 compatible with Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1?

Tags: 2011, 2013, dd4t

We have an application built using DD4T 2013 which we need to deploy with our Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1.

Is DD4T 2013 backward compatible enough to have this? Any help/pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik this should work. I didn't have to update the code when upgrading from DD4T 2011 SP1 to 2013 (SP1). This means that the Tridion CD API is backwards compatible. All you need to worry about is the Tridion CD dll's. The 'old' DD4T provider(s) are compiled against the current version. This can be solved by an `assemblyRedirect`.

Just give it a try on your development environment!

Comment: You do have to tell DD4T to use the 2011sp1 providers, by adding the following to the appSettings in your web.config: <add key="DD4T.ProviderVersion" value="Tridion2011sp1" />